# How to write sql query in python to update value in sql server table, just query needed?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

Sql server Table:

```
ID     Name   Emp_Id  Leave_Type  Days
123    Andy   1476    Sick        5
145    Eddy   1479    Casual      10
123    Andy   1475    Sick        5
```

python df:

```
ID     Name   Emp_Id  Leave_Type  Days
123    Andy   1476    Casual      13
185    Maddy  5678    Casual      10
```

i want to update my sql server table with python dataframe:
if  my sql table data already existed with same Id and Emp_Id then don't insert the record and if not insert the new record to the table.

example:

```
ID 123 , Emp 1476 already existed in sql table .
```

output:

Sql server Table

```
ID   Name   Emp_Id   Leave_Type    Days
123  Andy   1476     Sick          5
145  Eddy   1479     Casual        10
123  Andy   1475     Sick          5
185  Maddy  5678     Casual        10
```

Comment: Have you written any code to do this yet?

Comment: Read about some ORMs to help you with that task (SQLAlchemy, Peewee)

Comment: Since you reference SQL Server in your question presumably your "mysql" tag could be removed. Is that correct?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And I would argue that given the data you presented you shouldn't be updating your data. It seems to be tracking leave. That should have a row for each leave occurrence. Otherwise you are losing all your history.

Comment: Why would the last row of the output be `238  Maddy  7896     Casual        10`? In the dataframe, the Maddy row has totally different IDs. Please ensure your examples are consistent, then it's clear!

Comment: Anyway "if my sql table data already existed with same Id and Emp_Id then don't insert the record and if not insert the new record to the table"...isn't there a way you could prevent existing records from ever being in the dataframe? Then it would be a simple task of just inserting all records from the dataframe, as they would all be new. It's unclear how you build the frame like that, or why, but that sounds like maybe a better solution. You can compare each row to see if it already exists in the table, sure, but it's laborious and not very efficient.

Comment: I have updated question please do have a look.

Comment: the only way I would know whether that record is already existed or not is by reading the table and then create a logic

Comment: One thing you could do is have a unique auto-generated ID column for each row in your SQL table. You would include that ID in your dataframe as another column too. Then if you look at the dataframe, the existing rows will already have an ID, whereas new rows will not (because the database has not generated it yet)